# Java Designing to support Restful Api

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns

This is more how to design the system in java, which supports Restful Apis.

I have

```
public class A {
     private String attributeA;
     private String attributeAA;  
}

public class B extends A {
     private String attributeB;
}

public class C extends A {
     private String attributeC;
}

public class childOneOfB extends B {
}

public class childTwoOfB extends B 
}
```

Now the user can create A, B, C, childOneOfB, and ChildTwoOfB, so rest endpoints will look like

/v1/A - should fetch all information about A but also all subclasses B,C,childOneOfB and ChildTwoOfB but than how the client will know what kind of A is ? so is it good architecture to add enum type in 
class A, which says, A of what type?

```
public class A {
     private String attributeA;
     private String attributeAA;
     private enum { B, C; }   
}
public class B extends A {
     private String attributeB;
     private enum { childOneOfB, childTwoOfB; } 
}
```

In the end, endpoints should looks like

```
/v1/A - fetch A along with all subclasses 
/v1/B - fetch B alond with all subclasses
/v1/childOfOneB - fetch all childOfOneB
```

Comment: Why not reuse an existing standard such as jax-rs? There are many implementations out there

Comment: the way the `enum`s are defined in classes A and B - it creates unnecessary coupling because Class A or B is not supposed to know its children.

Comment: Thanks fge and asgs, can you explain in more details with example ?

Comment: There is a nice answer to this question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429717/jaxb-and-inheritance.

Comment: Thanks Dominik. Can I do this without jaxb with some java design pattern ? Lets say what if I am not exposing an endpoints

Comment: The question mentioned above is about inheritance over json / xml boundaries.

Comment: "do it with some design pattern" makes no sense. No, you can't "do it with some design pattern". That's not the way things work, you don't select a design pattern and that will automagically give you the perfect solution to your problem.