# How to use inheritance when reading from XML files using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb

Hi I have these classes right here:
As you can see Faculty and Student inherits name from Persons.
And faculty and student all have their unique attributes with that as well

```
public class Persons{
    protected String name;

    public Persons(){
        this(null);
    }
    public Persons(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }
    public String setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Student extends Persons{
    private String studentId;

    public Student(){
        this(null,null);
    }
    public Student(String name,String studentId){
        this.name = name;
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }



}
public class Faculty extends Persons{
    private String facultyId;

    public Faculty(){
        this(null,null);
    }
    public Faculty(String name,String facultyId){
        this.name = name;
        this.facultyId = facultyId;
    }
}
```

Provided that I have these XML files:

```
<persons>
    <student>
        <name>Example 1</name>
        <studentid>id</studentid>
    </student>
    <student>
        <name>Example 1</name>
        <studentid>id</studentid>
    </student>
</persons>
```

and the Faculty XML file:

```
<persons>
    <faculty>
        <name>Example 1</name>
        <facultyid>id</facultyid>
    </faculty>
    <faculty>
        <name>Example 1</name>
        <facultyid>id</facultyid>
    </faculty>
</persons>
```

how would I set up the classes for unmarshalling from the xml files. I have done this with normal xml files where there is not inheritance, but I was just wondering how would I do this without writing the same attributes in two classes. Thank You!

Comment: You might try searching around a little bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429717/jaxb-and-inheritance

Comment: I have been searching. I am just having a hard time understanding how am I suppose to save a list of Students. Would I set that attribute in Persons class or Students class. I know you would usually do it like this: List<Persons.Students> student

Comment: @Brenden1995 Don't have time for the full answer - but you can do this on the schema side with substitution groups and on JAXB side with `@XmlElementRef`. Also check `xsi:type`.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritence doesn't complicate anything when marshaling or unmarshalling using `JAXB`.

One thing to note here: in your Java classes you have fields named `studentId` and `facultyId` (with capital I letters) but in XML these elements appear with small i letters: `<studentid>` and `<facultyid>`. Either you make those written the same, or you have to tell JAXB what will be the XML element names storing the values of these fields with annotation like this:

```
public class Student extends Persons {
    @XmlElement(name = "studentid")
    private String studentId;

    // ... rest of your class
}

public class Faculty extends Persons {
    @XmlElement(name = "facultyid")
    private String facultyId;

    // ... rest of your class
}
```

Now that we told how the id fields are represented in XML files, we have to create wrapper classes to read a *collection* of students or a *collection* of faculties:

```
public class Students {
    @XmlElement(name = "student")
    public List<Student> students;
}

public class Faculties {
    @XmlElement(name = "faculty")
    public List<Faculty> faculties;
}
```

Now you have all you need. You can unmarshal the XML files like this:

```
Students students = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("students.xml"), Students.class);
Faculties faculties = JAXB.unmarshal(new File("faculties.xml"), Faculties.class);
```

Comment: You define _different_ properties in `Student`/`Person` and `Students`/`Persons` which is not so interesting (not too much inheritance). An interesting part would be to have just one `id` property in `Person` or just one collection property (`people`, or whatever) in `Persons` mapped differently by superclasses. I.e. `id` as `studentId` in `Student` or `facultyId` in `Faculty`.

Comment: @lexicore No, I'm not defining properties, the questioner defined them. I'm just using the classes he/she provided. The `name` field is the common in the hierarchy, and the custom id fields are the additions in suclasses. Your comment should be posted on the question itself.

Comment: You are right, this is not a part of this question.