# Determine subclass when unmarshalling with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I will try to provide a SSCCE of my problem.

I have this hierarchy of classes:

Class Base:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({ A.class, B.class })
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Base {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String baseData;

    public String getBaseData() {
        return baseData;
    }

    public void setBaseData(String baseData) {
        this.baseData = baseData;
    }
}
```

Class A extends Base

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="A", propOrder = { "dataA1", "dataA2" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "Base", namespace = "")
public class A extends Base {
    private String dataA1;
    private String dataA2;

    public String getDataA1() {
        return dataA1;
    }

    public void setDataA1(String dataA1) {
        this.dataA1 = dataA1;
    }

    public String getDataA2() {
        return dataA2;
    }

    public void setDataA2(String dataA2) {
        this.dataA2 = dataA2;
    }
}
```

Class B extends Base

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name="B", propOrder = { "dataB1", "dataB2" })
@XmlRootElement(name = "Base", namespace = "")
public class B extends Base {
    private String dataB1;
    private String dataB2;

    public String getDataB1() {
        return dataB1;
    }

    public void setDataB1(String dataB1) {
        this.dataB1 = dataB1;
    }

    public String getDataB2() {
        return dataB2;
    }

    public void setDataB2(String dataB2) {
        this.dataB2 = dataB2;
    }
}
```

But when I try to test it:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Base base = new A();
        base.setBaseData("BaseDataA");
        ((A) base).setDataA1("DataA1");
        ((A) base).setDataA2("DataA2");

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Base.class, A.class, B.class);

            // Marshal the object
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(base, sw);

            // Unmarshal the object
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            String generatedXml = sw.toString();
            System.out.println(generatedXml);
            Base objectFromUnmarshall = (Base) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(generatedXml));
            System.out.println(objectFromUnmarshall);

            // Re-marshal the object
            System.out.println("");
            sw = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(objectFromUnmarshall, sw);
            System.out.println(sw.toString());
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Base baseData="BaseDataA">
    <dataA1>DataA1</dataA1>
    <dataA2>DataA2</dataA2>
</Base>

jaxb.B@5c0369c4

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Base baseData="BaseDataA"/>
```

I marchal an object A, but when unmarshalling it creates an instance of B!

Why? How can I tell him to unmarshalh to the good instance?

**NOTE:** I am using Sun JAXB implementation and I cannot change it.

Comment: I assume `dataB1` etc. are not filled in the unmarshalled instance, right?

Comment: This might help (although it's about unmarshalling Json but it probably applies to XML as well): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429717/jaxb-and-inheritance

Comment: Thanks for our answer Thomas. I have apply that solution using the type (I have edited my question) but it does not work. No, dataB1 et dataB2 are null.

Comment: Could you try with a `type` element?

Comment: Yes I have added the @XmlType(name... but in my case it does not work (same result). I guess because I cannot set subtypes (@JsonSubTypes) as in the JSON case.

Comment: No what I meant is could you provide a field `type` to `Base` resp. a `<type>` tag to the XML?

Comment: Hi, my real XML is strictly validated and I cannot add new fields to it as type. Anyway I have added it just to test and is does not difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way I have found to handle it is to use an XMLAdapter (based in [this great article](https://dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using)).

```
public class BaseAdapter  extends XmlAdapter<BaseAdapter.BaseHandler,Base>{

    @Override
    public Base unmarshal(BaseHandler baseHandler) throws Exception {
        if (null == baseHandler) {
            return null;
        }
        if (null != baseHandler.dataA1) {
            A a = new A();
            a.setDataA1(baseHandler.dataA1);
            a.setDataA2(baseHandler.dataA2);            
            return a;
        } else {
            B b = new B();
            b.setDataB1(baseHandler.dataB1);
            b.setDataB2(baseHandler.dataB2);
            return b;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BaseHandler marshal(Base base) throws Exception {
         if (null == base) {
            return null;
        }
        BaseHandler baseHandler = new BaseHandler();
        if (base instanceof A) {
            A a = (A) base;
            baseHandler.dataA1 = a.getDataA1();
            baseHandler.dataA2 = a.getDataA2();
        } else {
            B b = (B) base;
            baseHandler.dataB1 = b.getDataB1();
            baseHandler.dataB2 = b.getDataB2();
        }
        return baseHandler;
    }

    public static class BaseHandler {
        public String dataA1;
        public String dataA2;
        public String dataB1;
        public String dataB2;
    }
}
```

[Here you are the complete SSCCE code](https://github.com/profesorfalken/Examples/tree/master/src/main/java/org/profesorfalken/examples/xml/jaxb/subclasses) if somebody is interested.